# Проблема с сокет-клиентом: bind возвращает -1

Tags: c++, сокет

Не могу задействовать функцию bind. При старте программы все работает отлично, но когда дело доходит до функции bind, то bind возвращает "-1". Спасибо.

Вот исходник:

**КЛИЕНТ**

```
#include <cstdlib>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <winsock.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");
char url[100];
int port;
char my_name[30] = "ASA";
std::cout << "Url: ";
cin >> url;
cout << endl;
std::cout << "Port: ";
cin >> port;
cout << endl;
 

  
WSADATA WsaData;
if (int err = WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WsaData) != 0)
{
        std::cout << "Socket not Loaded!\n";
        }else{
      std::cout << "Socket Loaded  \n";
}        

  
   int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == -1){
        std::cout << "Error! Socket no created.\n" ;      
               }else{
                     std::cout << "Socket Create.\n";
                     }
            
    
sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
addr.sin_port=htons(port);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(url);
int locate; 
locate = connect(sock, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

if (locate < 0){
           
        std::cout << "Fatal Error!\n";   
           system("pause");
           }else{
    char cut[10000];
    char get[10000];
    send(sock, my_name, 30, 0);
    recv(sock, get, 10000, 0);
    cout << get << endl;
    std::cout<<"Enter get: ";
    std::cin>>cut;
                 
             send(sock, cut, 10000, 0);
             
                               system("pause");
                 
                 }
    }
```

**СЕРВЕР**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 char client_name[30]; 
 char sv_name[30];  
    WSADATA WsaData;
    if (int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Socket not Loaded!\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Socket Loaded  \n";
    }
    
    gethostname(sv_name, 30);
    
     int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); /* исправлено sock*/
    if (sock == -1) { /* исправлено sock */
        std::cout << "Error! Socket no created.\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Socket Create.\n";
    }
    
    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(8080); /* исправлено */
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* исправлено */
    
   int bindet = bind(sock, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
   if (bindet == -1){
         std::cout << "Binding Error!\n"; 
            
            system("pause"); 
              }else {
                   int listening = listen (sock, 100);

                  
                                
         std::cout << "Server Name: " << sv_name << endl << "Wait for connecting ...\n"; 
      int acc = accept(sock, (sockaddr*)&addr, 0);  
        recv(acc, client_name, 30, 0); 
        
                              cout <<"Connected: " << client_name << "\n";
                              if (client_name == "ASA"){
                                              
                               char urls[100];               
                              send(acc, sv_name, strlen(sv_name) + 1, 0);                 
                              int rec = recv(acc, urls, 100, 0); 
                               if (rec > 0){
                               int i;              
                                              
        while(i < 100){
                send(acc, urls, 30, 0);
                
                ++i;
                }
                system("pause"); 
                }
              }}
                 
}
```

Comment: @Денис Фазиль, подкорректируйте форматирование кода пожалуйста.

Comment: Проанализируйте код ошибки в errno (печать текста ошибки -- perror). И ещё, зачем вам обязательно привилегированные порты, т.е. с номером меньше 1024?

Comment: `socket = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);` Константы AF_INET и PF_INET равны, но идеологически правильней писать PF_INET (хотя на результат оно естественно не повлияет). Вы же просто пропустили вызов функции. Очепятка.

Comment: А вы отличий не видите. В одном случае это вызов процедуры socket c тремя параметрами, в другом -- присвоение переменной socket выражения (AF_INET,..). Какое значение присваивается: 0 или AF_INET -- не помню, смотрите описание операции "," (в C/C++ это операция).

Comment: @Денис Фазиль, судя по исправлениям Вы ничего не прочитали о сокетах с момента, когда Вам дали ответы.

INADDR_ANY в connect() естественно использовать нельзя. Для connect() нужно прописать адрес сервера (IP). Про INADDR_ANY говорилось, что его **можно** использовать в bind().

Еще раз советую написать одну программу клиент и одну сервер.

**Клиент:** *socket() connect() send()*

**Сервер:** *socket() bind() listen() accept() recv()*

Comment: Про INADDR_ANY и то что его в connect() нельзя я это помню, но я незнаю как туда впихнуть что то другое Dev-Cpp пишет ошибку когда я на место INADDR_ANY пишу что-то другое. Пробовал через #define таже история. И пожалуста можно на ТЫ. А читать литературу не могу я сейчас в дороге. Даже если буду читать всеравно в голову ни чего не войдет. Приеду домой и примусь изучать!!!

Comment: @Денис Фазиль, постарайтесь:

1. Как-то отмечать исправления в своей программе (например комментируя предыдущий вариант, и добавляя комментарий к новому (типа **вариант 22**));

2. Компилировать программу. IMHO htonl("localhost") не должно пройти;

3. Почитать (**внимательно**) man о вызываемых Вами функциях.

Comment: @avp А в Dev-Cpp тоже man'ы (я его не видел ни разу)? А то помню лет несколько назад мне надо было такие фокусы под cygwin проделывать, так пришлось man'ы тащить с linux'ов. Ему возможно придётся говорить "man htonl" гуглу...

Comment: @alexlz, про Dev-Cpp ничего сказать не могу. 

Я в основном использую Linux, а в винде пишу на MinGW gcc, редактор везде - Emacs, компиляция и сборка - make;

man часто смотрю на http://www.opennet.ru (там хорошая подборка для разных ОС);

виндовые функции на http://msdn.microsoft.com (на конкретную функцию туда  обычно выхожу через Google (если в моих закладках ее еще нет)).

Comment: @pro - я откатил вашу правку с кучей благодарностей всем причастным, так как она искажает изначальный вопрос и делает его бесполезным для тех, кто придет сюда из поисковых систем. Более того, на нашем сайте принято выражать благодарность лайками и отметкой верного ответа, чего вы как раз не сделали.

Answer (score 2):

1. `bind()` для клиентского сокета Вам здесь **не нужен** !!!

Локальный адрес этому сокету будет присвоен автоматически в `connect()`. Если Вы все же хотите присвоить клиенту конкретный адрес, то в поле **addr.sin_addr.s_addr** надо поместить один из локальных IP (или константу `INADDR_ANY`).

1. В `memcpy()` копировать IP сервера надо в поле **addr.sin_addr.s_addr**, а не в `sin_family`.

Comment: Ну там непонятно, у него и клиентская и серверная части в одной программе (что ему ещё придётся как-то куда-то разносить). А насчёт адресов s_addr и s_addr.sin_family -- некрасиво, но адрес-то один и тот же.

Comment: Смотрю на код (в вопросе) и не вижу accept() (а вот connect() есть). 

Делаю вывод, что это клиентская часть, а bind() здесь из серии "*слышал звон, да не знаю, где он*".

Comment: Да я ему в ответе это уже писал. Но всякие gethostname, gethostbyname... Может я ошибаюсь, но сильно непонятно, чего же он хочет. (вероятно какая-то учебная работа -- для себя или для преп.)

Comment: Ну и ещё один совет: разбирайтесь с написанием сервера и клиента отдельно, а пока пишите один, для отладки используйте netcat (http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat)

Comment: Читайте книги. accept -- приём соединения сервером (после установления tcp-соединения с портом, ожидающим соединения после вызова listen). accept возвращает сокет (другой), через которой уже идёт обмен с клиентом (через серверный сокет обмена нет). Т.е. для сервера цепочка socket->bind->listen->accept(которых м.быть много). Для клиента socket->connect. Ну и заполнение разных структур.

Comment: Добавил ответ, посмотрите. Сервер (в другом окне) `nc -l 4000`

Comment: Только виндовую-то WSAStartup не забывайте, и прототипы функций там могут находится в других .h-файлах

Answer (score 1):

Для начала: Вы забыли вызвать функцию `socket` в строке `socket = (AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);`
(Ну и мой комментарий остаётся актуальным)
Далее HostName у Вас читается с cin и заполняется gethostname. Зачем? 
И вообще странно, что у Вас в одной программе (и одном потоке/нити) и сервер, и клиент.
Ну listen и accept, видимо будут позднее.

Добавка:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

   int sock;
   sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (sock == -1) {
       perror("socket");
       std::cout << "Error! Socket no created.\n";
   } else {
       std::cout << "Socket Create.\n";
   }

   sockaddr_in addr;
   addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   addr.sin_port = htons(4000);
   addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

   int connection = connect(sock, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

   if (connection < 0) {
       std::cout << "Fatal Error!\n";
   } else {
       char message[1000];
       std::cout << "Enter get: ";
       std::cin >> message;
       send(sock, message, strlen(message), 0);
   }
}
```

Поправил ваше творение. Но определение SOCKET у меня отсутствует, заменил на int. Имя socket используется для системного вызова, поэтому переменную обозвал sock. Адрес 127.0.0.1 преобразую функцией inet_addr.
Добавил вызов perror при ошибке создания сокета. Поменял номер порта на 4000 (непривилегированный). В send длину сообщения вычисляю с помощью strlen. Да, и сокеты надо закрывать. Здесь он закрывается при выходе из программы, а вообще желательно это делать явно.

Вариант от 26.01.12:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");

    WSADATA WsaData;
    if (int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Socket not Loaded!\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Socket Loaded  \n";
    }

    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); /* исправлено sock*/
    if (sock == -1) { /* исправлено sock */
        std::cout << "Error! Socket no created.\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Socket Create.\n";
    }

    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(4000); /* исправлено */
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); /* исправлено */

    int connection;
    connection = connect(sock, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)); /* исправлено sock */
    if (connection < 0) {
        std::cout << "Fatal Error!\n";
        //system("pause"); /* а так лучше не делать. Вызывать cmd.exe... Ну введите что-нибудь с cin */
    } else {
        char message[1000];
        std::cout << "Enter get: ";
        std::cin >> message;

        send(sock, message, strlen(message), 0); /* исправлено sock, strlen -- иначе на сервер приходит куча мусора */
    }
}
```

Оттранслировано i586-mingw32msvc-g++ (GCC) 4.4.2, собирал и с libwsock32.a, и с libws2_32.a (где-то видел, что ws2_32 предпочтительней) . Проверял на nc -l 4000 в другом окне.

Comment: В винде обязательно надо начинать с WSAStartup(), а perror() для сокетных функций в ней печатает ерунду (они в винде errno не меняют).

Там есть какая-то функция, возвращающая код при ошибках с сокетом, но преобразовать его в текст у меня терпения не хватило (поэтому ее имя и не помню).

Comment: alexlz, за поправку спасибо НО! Проверил код при запуске программы сокет грузится гдето 2 секунды и всеравно Error!!!!!

Comment: Ну что я могу сказать. Покажите текст программы (целиком, с `#include`'ами). Попробую запустить под wine (WinXP загружать совсем неохота).

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо что дополнил но толку мало: мой Dev его легко компилирует но!!! при запуске всеравно "connect() == -1" незнаю даже что с этим делать? Я собирал с ws2_32.

Comment: Вылетает сразу, или ждёт и дохнет по таймауту? А текст именно мой, или ваш с правками? И ещё, netcat-то запущен и висит на порту 4000?
(т.е. команда `netstat -a` про порт 4000 говорит LISTENING)?

Comment: Рад за Вас! Правда исходников не вижу, но это не мои проблемы.

Comment: Вон в верху ^

Comment: Спасибо. А вот еще вопрос а как зделать чтобы клиент и сервер работали не только локально?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. На разных компьютерах? Так если есть возможность установить соединение -- никаких проблем. Просто connect'у дайте другой адрес (не localhost == 127.0.0.1), а адрес на том компьютере, где запущен сервер. Если проходят ping'и, то с высокой долей вероятности (но не 100%), будет работать и Ваша связка. Ну а если надо адрес задавать в символьном виде, то придётся использовать вызовы разрешения имён, (напр. тот же gethostbyname)

Comment: Все нормально уже работает я просто ip неправильно ввел! Спасибо!Спокойной ночи. :)

Comment: Был у меня в студенческие времена товарищ, у которого 7 утра было поздним вечером, а 7 вечера -- утром. Не мог понять, когда же зимой светло-то бывает.

Comment: не у меня ща на часах 5 утра!!!